# Initializing 2 dimensional array and get null point exception and out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arrays

This is my first time ever using one of these so i'm sorry if there is a question already like this. but here is my homework description for the first two steps. 1.    Declare a two-dimensional array that hold int type values, with its first dimension set to be 3. This array is to hold the number of credit hours for each student in three classes. However, the number of students in these three classes may vary. 
2.  Use the Scanner class to ask for one integer input, representing the number of students in the first class. Repeat this process for the other two classes.

and this is my code lines 18 - 26 i keep getting out of bounds exceptions and null point exceptions

```
int[][] ragArray = new int[3][];

for(int i = 0; i < ragArray.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < ragArray[i].length; j++){
        System.out.println("Enter the number of students in the class: ");
        ragArray[i][j] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

sorry it's so long :/

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is fine, but you need also set the other dimension of the array. Currently you have array that has 3 null values, so ragArray[0][0] will be null.

Since you dont know the other dimension of the array, you will first ask the number of students (not inside loop), and then use the given value when creating the 2 dimensional array.

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of students in the class: ");
int students = input.nextInt();
int[][] ragArray = new int[3][students];
//now you have the array to store students
```

Comment: You didn't read the question.  You *don't know* how many students are in each class, so it makes perfect sense to use a jagged array here.  Fixing them all to 3 will mean that only 3 students ever will have their information stored in this data structure.

Comment: Yes I did, i just did't give full answer to homework, that's not a reason to downvote.

Comment: There's a difference between giving a "full" answer and giving "the wrong" answer.  Your original answer was incorrect because it didn't even point them in the right direction.

Comment: Yes it did, just like libik's answer was too, I don't see a reason why you had to downvote that too.

Comment: Okay.  I'm not going to get into more detail than this, but at the time, *your answer was wrong*, so I acted accordingly.  Their answer was incomplete, *so I acted accordingly*.  I was being realistic with my expectations of both of your answers.  Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

Its 2D = arrays of array.

If you have nothing stored in array and if you do not create it, it is is null.

Therefore all your `ragArray[0-2]` is equal to null.

When you try to access lenght of null, it throws exception, here : `ragArray[i].length`

Comment: ...Yes, this is a given from the error that is being encountered.  What is required here is how one can overcome it with respect to the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your jagged array doesn't have another array declared for it, so `ragArray[i]` will fail.

The point of jagged arrays is that the array you place there is dynamic; that means the length between them all is not uniform.  If you're getting that information based on the number of students in the class, then perhaps *that* should be the length of the array instead.

So what we'll do is create a new array inside the loop, do our operation of reading and so forth with respect to that loop, then attach the array we've created to our jagged array *at the end* of the processing.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ragArray.length; i++) {

    System.out.print("Enter the number of students in the class: ");
    int[] students = new int[input.nextInt()];
    input.nextLine();
    // loop over students instead
    ragArray[i] = students;

}
```